# Join on two of the same foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select

I have this table below

```
Table Assignments
AssignmentID:  int
LinkedTo:  varchar(50)
AssignedUser:  int
AssignedBy:  int
```

where `AssignedBy` and `AssignedUser` are foreign keys from the table `Users`. Here is what `Users` looks like

```
UserKey:int
Username:varchar(50)
```

How can I do an inner join where I get both `AssignedBy` and `AssignedUser`?
The following gives me one of them but how can I get both? By the way `AssignedBy` and `AssignedUser` are two different `Users`. I'm trying to get `Users.Username`

```
select Users.Username
from Assignments
INNER JOIN Users ON Assignments.UserKey = Users.UserKey
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want both user names on one row, you have to join `Users` twice, like

```
SELECT UA.Username AS AssignedUserName, UB.Username AS AssignedByUserName
    FROM Assignments A
    INNER JOIN Users UA ON A.AssignedUser = UA.UserKey
    INNER JOIN Users UB ON A.AssignedBy = UB.UserKey;
```

If your goal is to have all user names regardless wether it comes from `AssignedUser` or from `AssignedBy`, you have to use `UNION`

```
SELECT U.Username
    FROM Assignments A
    INNER JOIN Users U ON A.AssignedUser = U.UserKey
UNION SELECT U.Username
    FROM Assignments A
    INNER JOIN Users U ON A.AssignedBy = U.UserKey;
```

Note however that this will remove duplicate user names. If you want to keep duplicates, use `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

You need two joins:

```sql
SELECT assigned.username AS assigned_username
       assigned_by.username AS assigned_by_username
FROM   assignments a
JOIN   users assigned ON a.assigneduser = assigned.userkey
JOIN   users assigned_by ON a.assignedby = assigned_by.userkey
```